# At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7 (-19033) Unable to validate your application. - (null)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, app-store

I am developing an Ipad only application but i am getting much problem in "Application failed codesign verification due to invalid entitlements" error when i trying to submit on apple store  and also some issue which i am mentioning with what i have done below. I am using Xcode 4.3.2 and and IOS 5.1 for development and Target is IOS 5.0

```
1. iPad: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7 (-19033)
```

for this i did like other people mention

```
ARCHS = armv7 armv6
```

i add Architecture armv7 but its not working here is the link of build setting I have no Entitlement file as people told me but if you can help me

[image]

[image]

```
2. Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

3. Unable to extract entitlements from application: (null) (-19045)
```

This is the comeplete error, ihope you guy take me futher, thanks

```
Validate /Users/bourne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1-azcqbuzeebaybzdjeksuhyuvyrmw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1.app
    cd /Development/TurfNutritionTool_IOS_5.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/bourne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1-azcqbuzeebaybzdjeksuhyuvyrmw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1.app

warning: iPad: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7 (-19033)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/bourne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1-azcqbuzeebaybzdjeksuhyuvyrmw/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/TurfNutritionTool_ver_5.1.app/Info.plist
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
AssertMacros: exec,  file: codesign.c, line: 170
AssertMacros: binary,  file: codesign.c, line: 235
AssertMacros: code_signatures,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 945
 - (null)

warning: Unable to extract entitlements from application: (null) (-19045)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)
```

Comment: This is the additional link your your information
http://www.flickr.com/photos/79040977@N07/6929901726/in/photostream
http://www.flickr.com/photos/79040977@N07/6929899420/in/photostream

Comment: How are you building your app-store version?

Comment: I created new scheme distribution and did all the setting and then i archive the application and when i validate it fails

Comment: Which configuration is that scheme linked with?

Comment: Are you talking about debug and release. It's release

Comment: Yes, that is what I was talking about - so Release - ok, thats correct.

Comment: well i am really don't know what is the wrong here :)  I heard that New Xcode IDE create some problem and u should use older version? should i do that

Comment: Xcode 4.3.2 is totally fine - those rumors you heard about are related to older versions of Xcode4.

Comment: can you tell me what can i do or some place where we can have little chat to explain it better. plz i will be thank full to you

Comment: Your current SO score does not allow moving this discussion to a chat.

Comment: ya , but yahoo or msn can help if u can help,  i am really new in IOS and only developer and at the end i am so frustrated. if u can give ur valuable time on yahoo chat or msn or even facebook where u like i will be thanks full to you

Answer (score 4):

Solved this problem by setting **Architectures** to **armv7** only and changing **Deployment Target** to **4.3** (it was 4.0 before).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and fixed it by setting **Build Active Architecture Only** to **No** (it is actually a major speed up during development to have it set to **Yes!**)

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following settings in your apps :

In the Info.plist. Check for "Required device capabilities" info, and look the data inside. You should have 2 items (NSArray) : armv6 and armv7

Comment: No ARMV6 code needed for an iPad only app - there is no iPad using the arm6 platform.

Comment: i have added the armv7. Should i add the armv6?

Comment: No armv7 should be enough, sorry I did not see it was for iPad ^_^

Comment: What should i do else please help me