# validating an iPhone app archive

Tags: app-store, xcode4.3, armv7, entitlements

Trying to send an app to Apple's App Store. Xcode 4.3.2. Successfully sent the app out to users via testflightapp and now want to send it to the store. When I try to distribute the app via the organizer I get these three validation errors:

- iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6
- Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.
- Unable to extract entitlements from application: (null)

I'm thinking I should work from the bottom up as I only had the first error when I sent embarked on solving this issue, and from everything I read, entitlements are not necessary when submitting to the app store.

I had a Entitlements.plist. I tried with it deleted. I tried with it created fresh. The Entitlements section of Targets->App->Summary is unchecked/clear. The Targets->App->Build Settings->Deployment section did have "Entitlements.plist" listed for the Install Owner/Group as well as the Alternate Install Owner/Group. I've reset these to a group of "staff" and an owner of "pedstrom".

I've tried following instructions like this one: [At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7 (-19033) Unable to validate your application. - (null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152382/at-least-one-of-the-following-architectures-must-be-present-armv7-19033-un) to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem may due to an invalid setting for the Build
Variants build setting.  Valid settings are **normal**, **profile**, and **debug**.
For submission to the app store, this setting should be **normal**.

Here's how to fix this:

First update the Project build settings:

- Click on Project -> `<your project>` -> Build Settings
- Search for "build variants"
- Click on the arrow icon next to Build Variants in the search results to expand the section
- Remove any existing entries and replace them with **normal**

Next update the Target build settings:

- Click on Targets -> `<your project>` -> Build Settings
- Search for "build variants"
- Click on the arrow icon next to Build Variants in the search results
  to expand the section
- Remove any existing entries and replace them with **normal**

Comment: in my project I already had build variants as normal, so it didn't work for me

Comment: Thanks! I spent over an hour on this one. Turns out Build Variants was set to "armv6" for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this snag for a few different reasons and have found it especially useful to use the validate function  in the organizer before actually submitting. It can give you clues as to what is wrong that may not be included in the upload failed errors.