# iOS6 and XCode 4.5 - Unable to upload app to app store

Tags: trigger.io, forge

I made some changes and prepared to upload a newer version of my app to the app store that I built using trigger.io

The Application Loader show this error message:

"iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6"

Maybe the answer lies here: [validating an iPhone app archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540848/validating-an-iphone-app-archive) ?

I have successfully submitted apps to the Apple app store in the past... however, since upgrading for iOS6 I cannot.  What am I doing wrong?  Is it a build setting issue over at trigger.io?

Here is a screenshot: [image]

Comment: I was able to submit to the app store using `Trigger.io` and `iOS6` two weeks ago (API version 1.4.14). So its either broken since 1.4.15 or the issue is somewhat more specific.

Comment: @Patrick my config is using - "platform_version": "v1.4" - so that should always have me on the latest and greatest revision.

Comment: And "Forge tools running at version 3.3.17"

Comment: We are aware of a problem with packaging and have a fix in testing right now. We expect to deploy it on Monday, sorry for the inconvenience and I'll update here again soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed as of our v1.4.16 platform:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-16

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 4.5  support `armv7 and armv7s` architecture.

So please

```
1. select your Build architecture as Standard (armv7 &armv7s)
2. select deployment target as IOS 4.3 and 
3. add the following variable in the `info.plist`:-
    Required Device capabilities with Item0 values as armv7.
```

This will help you..

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at your build settings.

Under architectures you might see armv6 in the list.

However, Xcode4.5 no longer builds binaries for armv6. So although your settings says that they are being built, they are not. Application Loader is failing because you are missing the armv6 build even though you say that you are producing it.

If you remove armv6 from the list and rebuild, this problem goes away.